# Rounded corners on First and Last <li> item

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a top menu in my Wordpress theme, similiar to http://mailchimp.com/. As you can see from this menu, when 'Pricing' is active the background changes to white. I trying to implement the same effect on my menu.

The menu back ground currently has round corners:

```
#menu-main-menu{
    margin-top:66px;
    background: #eeeeee;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

no issues here.

But the problem occurs when 'Home' (first item in the menu) or 'Contact' (last item in the menu) are active, the corners are no longer rounded.

Obviously for 'Home' I only want the left hand corners rounded and for 'Contact' I want the right hand corners rounded. Here's what I'm trying at the moment (See CSS between START & STOP below) but it doesn't seem to be rounding the corners as I want.

```
            body > header .nav li a {
                            background: none;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            /*font-family: TitilliumText22L005, sans-serif;*/
                            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                            font-size: 13px;
                            color: #000000;
                            text-shadow: none;
                            text-transform: uppercase;
                            border-right: solid 1px #000000;
                        }

                        body > header .nav li:last-child a {
                            border-right: none;                                                     
                        }

                        body > header .nav > li.current-menu-item,
                        body > header .nav > li.current-menu-ancestor {
                            background: #c4c4c4;
                        }


        /* START: Its this bit below I'm trying to get working. */

            body > header .nav li:first-child .current_menu_item{                                               
                                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
                                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;             

                                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                                border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;                             
                            }

                            body > header .nav li:last-child .current_menu_item{                                
                                -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
                                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;                

                                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                                border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;                                
                            }
/* STOP */

    body > header .nav > li.current-menu-item > a,
                body > header .nav > li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
                body > header .nav > li.current-page-ancestor > a,
                body > header .nav > li.current_page_parent > a {               
                    /*background: #ffffff;*/
                    text-shadow: none;                              
                    box-shadow: none;                                       
                }
```

*UPDATE*
Posting HTML as requested.

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav">
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Quiénes Somos</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-18"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Servicios</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-17"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Noticias</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards, Stephen

Comment: Any way you could post an example of this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You know, `//` before a line doesn't make it a comment in CSS. Only `/* */`.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  From what you describe it sounds like there might be an issue between your container LI and the A tag.  What I want to see if if you're trying to round the "LI" or the "A" tag.  Your CSS isn't make a lot of sense for me without the HTML because you're saying "take the first LI and then inside that there will be a class called 'current_menu_item' and round those corners.  I would have expected you would be rounding the LI tag but I'm guessing you're rounding the A instead, but I wonder why you're using a class then.

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: I've updated the post with more info. @ChristoferEliasson What I mean is its not rounding the corners they are square.

Comment: @Fozzyuw Yes, I'm trying to round the LI tag. This is a Wordpress site, and the base functionality places classes on the active LI tag. I was trying to use these classes and identify the FIRST & LAST LI TAG, then apply my styling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a background color set on the li but you're rounding it's child element's border. Since the li has the background-color applied to it, you need to round its corners and not the li's child. Also, if you want that element to always have rounded corners, you don't need to apply the .current-menu-item class. So that part of your code should look like this:

```
header .nav li:last-child{                                
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;                

    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;                 
}
```

It should be the same for the first-child. Except of course you need to change the properties from right to left. This will apply the rounded corners at all times regardless of whether or not the li is the current item. If you want to change the border radius for the current item you need to redefine that property later on in the stylesheet. Otherwise it will stay exactly the same.

Comment: Alex, thanks very much for that. Simple answer in the end. I was over thinking the whole process. That worked a treat.

Comment: @Stephen I notice that you don't have the `-webkit` prefix in there. Not sure if Chrome and Safari still use it for border-radius, or if they have moved over to the standard CSS way of writing border-radius, but it is worth noting at least.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Thanks Christofer, I've included the -webkit prefix now.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dabblet.com/gist/1845274) is a simple example of what you are trying to accomplish.

```
li{display:inline;}
li a{display:inline-block; padding:20px; background:red;}
li:first-child a{border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;  }
li:last-child a{border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;  }
li a:hover,li a.active {background: salmon;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSfiddle with 2 examples:  http://jsfiddle.net/9YtfT/

The first horizontal list rounds the corners of the LI.  The second uses the A tag as the border and rounds them.

Depending on your browser (I think it's a Firefox thing) but rounding the borders of the LI tag can have an effect when there's a background color of a block level child (ie. the A tag).  So, to get a cleaner effect, it would be better to round the A tag.

But there's an example of both.

UPDATE

@Stephen The CSS is failing because of this selector:

```
.nav li:first-child .current_menu_item{
...
}
```

The selector is looking for a *child* element inside of the first *LI* tag with a class called "current_menu_item".   Your HTML puts this class *on* the LI tag, not beneath it.

To fix your css, you need to remove the space.

```
.nav li:first-child.current_menu_item{
...
}
```

This tells the browser to find the first-child LI with that has a class "current_menu_item".  I think that will work.   Of course, it begs to ask, if you're trying to round the first child, why are you targeting the "current_menu_item" class?  You can remove it all together.

```
.nav li:first-child{
...
}
```

UPDATE 2

I updated the JSFiddle to include class names to give a closer example to Stephen's situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/9YtfT/3/